# Entity SQL: Include?

Tags: entity-framework

I am looking for equivalent of the following for Entity SQL.

```
from row in Parent_Table
select new{
             Parent_Table.include("child_table").Select("SomeField").Max(),
             row
          }
```

Whereas this is part of whole query

(how can i create a sub query while the lazy loading is off ?)

as i try

```
myObjectQuery.Include("Proj_PF_" + state_Year).Select("phisicalImprovement").Max();
```

phisicalImprovement is a field of Proj_PF_" + state_Year and my query is to an other table

get the fallowing exception

```
'phisicalImprovement' is not a member of 'Transient.collection[NezaratModel.Proj_PF_58_89(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]'. To extract a property of a collection element, use a subquery to iterate over the collection. Near simple identifier
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent in ESQL and it should not be needed because when you call ESQL you are using `ObjectQuery<>` so you just pass your ESQL command to the `ObjectQuery` instance and should be able to call `Include` for it:

```
var query = (new ObjectQuery<YourEntity>("SELECT VALUE ...")).Include("SomerRelation");
```

Comment: myobjectquery.Include("Proj_" + state_Year).Select("phisicalImprovement").Max();but it didn't work for me

Comment: Because it wasn't valid ESQL query. You don't need Include if you are going to use aggregation.

Comment: :Thanx but how can i access max of some filed of an other table which is a child of the table which im querying ?